# Wi-Fi auto-disconnect for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, network, wifi

Is there an app to disconnect an iPhone from a Wi-Fi router at a specific time, other than just turning off Wi-Fi?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? As Chris says,  a lot of routers have this kind of setting, so that may be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to configure the router to only allow WiFi access to the iPhone during certain times of day.  This isn't a connection timeout so much as a parental control over the time of day WiFi is allowed.  The setting is located in [your routers admin interface](http://192.168.1.1/).